# Obtaining values via buttons

Tags: python, html, button, cherrypy

So, I've been working on an app that lets people cast votes. To do so, I've written the following code in HTML:

```
<form action="api/vote" method="post">
    <p>Photo ID</p>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" size="15" maxlength="40"/>
    <p><input type="submit" name="vote1" value="Upvote"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="vote2" value="Downvote"/></p>
    <p><input type="reset" value="Clear"/></p>
</form>
```

I did this because I need the ID value and the vote for future usage. I can obtain the ID, however I don't know how to get the vote buttons to return values. I'd need vote1 to return "1" and vote2 to return "-1" for example.

I'd need these values to be arguments for a CherryPy method defined as such:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def vote(self, id=None, vote=None):
    #code that doesn't matter for this question

    if vote == 1:
        #upvote code
    elif vote == -1:
        #downvote code
    else
        return "You're not suppose to be here!"
```

Does anyone know how I could get values from the HTML onto the CherryPy file? Or know which button was pressed to get the values from there?

Comment: Try to give the same name for both vote submit buttons `name="vote"` and then check in your cherrypy handler whether `vote == 'Upvote'` or `vote == 'Downvote'`

Comment: @VsevolodKulaga Thanks for the answer but that didnt work. I get an error "NameError: global name 'Upvote' is not defined" which brings us the same issue, which is: how do I instance/get the value.

Comment: Can you provide your updated code that does not work please?